# Can I start a bounty on a already answered question?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I came across with the following question

> [Definition of "descends to"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168939/definition-of-descends-to)

I think that is a question that many students of algebraic geometry (and probably many others) have in the beginning, and I don't know any formal reference for the question. Although the accepted answer gives an idea of what it means to say that a map descents to another, I don't think this is enough, I would like to see a formal definition or a reference.

Because of this, I would like to know if I can start a bounty on this question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you can also see the "start a bounty" buttom in that post. In general you see that in a post, then yes.

Comment: Yeah, maybe my question was not clear. It should be, is it acceptable to start a bounty on a question that already has an answer?

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**.

For example, you might think that the existing answers, whether one has been accepted or not, don't fully address the question (sometimes a reader has a different opinion about what constitutes a "fully satisfying answer" than the original poster of the question). Another thing you can do is use a bounty to award an *existing* answer you think is really awesome (so in a sense you *can* upvote a question multiple times :P).